# Cartesian product of- records of a single column on single table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

Hi I would like to know whether, is it possible to do a 'Cartesian product' operation
on column records. Here is the scenario:

```
PIID1           PIID2
```

---

```
PIID11         (Intially empty)
PIID12         (Initially empty)
PIID13         (Initially empty)
```

required output(removed self relations) :

```
PIID1             PIID2  
-------- --------------------  
PIID11           PPIID12  
PIID11           PPIID13  
PPIID12          PIID11  
PPIID12          PPIID13  
PPIID13          PPIID12  
PPIID13          PPIID11
```

please post your solutions .

Comment: Do you the result with a `SELECT` or you want the table to be updated (and rows added)?

Comment: Do you need the solution for ALL tagged DBS ?

Comment: @ypercube : I wanted to make this like a dynamic table update using a query

Comment: @DanFromGermany:I am afraid to say this,but I did not get your question.would you please enlighten me regarding 'what is dbs ?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SELF JOIN`:

```
Select 

    a.pIID1 as PIID1, 
    b.pIID1 as PIID2
    from 
    table a, 
    (Select pIID1 from table) b
    WHERE  a.pIID1<>b.PIID1
```

Comment: I see a join but not a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

First insert the new rows with a self-join:

```
INSERT INTO tableX
    (piid1, piid2)
SELECT
    a.piid1, b.piid1
FROM 
    tableX  a
  CROSS JOIN
    tableX  b
WHERE
    a.piid1 <> b.piid1 ;
```

Then delete the original rows:

```
DELETE FROM tableX
WHERE piid2 IS NULL ;
```